# How to execute the method again if there is an error

Tags: node.js, typescript

[image]

If the method `getApiGoogleDesktop` receives an error I would like to run it again infinitely

```
class PsiController {
  public async getApiGoogleDesktop(req: Request, res: Response) {

    console.log('Consumiendo API Google Desktop... ');

    let url = `${urlParams.url}?url=${urlParams.psiUrl}&key=${urlParams.key}&category=${urlParams.category[1]}&strategy=${urlParams.strategy[1]}&locale=${urlParams.locale}`;

    await Request.get(url, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
      if (error) {
        return error;
      }

      let data = JSON.parse(body);
      if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
        Request.get('http://localhost:3000/api/psi/desktop')
      }

      // ...

      return res.send(data);

    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont quite understand? Just call the method (getApiGoogleDesktop) again inside the if statement with the same params.

Comment: I tried this way `let data =  JSON.parse(body);
                if (data.error) {
                    console.log(data.error);
                    this.getApiGoogleDesktop(req, res)
                }`but I get an error

Comment: Assuming `this` is bound correctly, that is the way to do it. What error do you get?

Comment: `....\controllers\psiControllers.js:43
                    this.getApiGoogleDesktop(req, res);
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApiGoogleDesktop' of undefined`

Comment: That means `this` is undefined within the scope of that function. You'll need to tell it what `this` is by binding it to the instance of your class when you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "recursion" function to do this task. For this case, you can use a callback style function, it will easy to implement and understand.

```
class PsiController {
  public async getApiGoogleDesktop(req: Request, res: Response) {

    console.log('Consumiendo API Google Desktop... ');

    let url = `${urlParams.url}?url=${urlParams.psiUrl}&key=${urlParams.key}&category=${urlParams.category[1]}&strategy=${urlParams.strategy[1]}&locale=${urlParams.locale}`;

    const whenSuccess = (data) => { // callback in success case
      res.send(data);
    }

    const whenError = (error) => { // callback in error case. We catch "system" error like NetworkError
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }

    const forceRequest = (url: string, onSuccess: (data) => void, onError: (error) => void) => { // the recursion function
      Request.get(url, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
        if (error) {
          return onError(error); // stop
        }

        let data = JSON.parse(body);
        if (data.error) {
          console.log(data.error);
          return forceRequest(url, onSuccess, onError); // retry with original params
        }

        // ...

        onSuccess(data); // stop when successfully

      })
    }

    // start
    forceRequest(url, whenSuccess, whenError); // call recursion function, with above callbacks
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `while` loop where you set the `url` outside first, and then on error inside the loop.

Comment: which means calling the function recursively inside is tail-call optimizeable YAY DATA STRUCTURE CLASSES

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
     class PsiController {
        public async getApiGoogleDesktop(req: Request, res: Response) {

            console.log('Consumiendo API Google Desktop... ')
            let url = `${urlParams.url}?url=${urlParams.psiUrl}&key=${urlParams.key}&category=${urlParams.category[1]}&strategy=${urlParams.strategy[1]}&locale=${urlParams.locale}`

            const data = await makeRequest(url)
            return res.send(data)

            async function makeRequest(url) {
                return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
                    Request.get(url, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
                        if (error) {
                            return error
                        }
                        let data = JSON.parse(body)
                        if (data.error) {
                            console.log(data.error)
                            return makeRequest('http://localhost:3000/api/psi/desktop')
                        }
                        // ...
                        return resolve(data)
                    })

                })
            }
            //...
```